# Consolidate function in excel- Not getting the desired format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Its my first time using consolidate in excel 2010. Its working as expected, however I am not getting the desired format in the output table.

I have a summary tab for individual Test Plans. I am consolidating this data into a Master Summary but not getting the desired output of the table. What am I missing?

Test Plan 1
[image: TestPlan 1]

Test Plan 2
[image]

Summary after consolidation of 2 test plans

[image]

Notice that #Tests is towards the left (in a new row) and then the Workbook Name is present. I would like the Workbook Name to be displayed in the left most column and #Test should be after that (same row).

Desired output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to solve this problem with a formula instead of using data consolidation, but it has limitations on what the sheet tabs are named. I'll explain all details below.

As I understand it, you have several different sheets in your workbook, each sheet corresponding to a different "test plan", and then you have one "summary" sheet which contains all info about all test plans. So your tabs would look something like this:

[image]

In your "summary" sheet, you can paste this formula into cell `A2` (line break added for readability):

```
= IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Test Plan "&(ROW()-1)&"'!"
  &IF(COLUMN()=1,"A1",ADDRESS(4,COLUMN()-1))),"")
```

Drag this formula over to cell `L2` and then drag down as far as necessary. Note if you drag down too far, it isn't an issue because the `IFERROR(...,"")` part of the formula just returns blank cells if a match isn't found.

This formula will put your data in the desired format and the order of the test plans in the generated table will be in the same order of the tab names. In general I'm not a huge fan of using the volatile `INDIRECT` function, but in this case, it is the only option that I can think of.

**IMPORTANT!!** Of course, the major limitation to this scheme is that all test plan sheet tabs **must** be *exactly* of the form: `Test Plan #` because this is the tab name that the formula above is searching for. (Note that you can have more than 9 test plans and it will still work - it isn't limited to one character for the test plan number if you were wondering that.) If your sheets are not (or cannot) be named this, then this scheme will not work for you, but if you can handle changing your sheet tab names to this format, then this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to clarify the individual Test Plans are in separate workbooks. Each workbook has a Summary Tab and a Test Plan Name tab. The Test Plan name cannot be in the exact for Test Plan # as the names are already decided based on the features tested. I am trying to consolidate a master summary in a new workbook that looks at all the individual test plans summary and present and overall summary of the testing effort.

Comment: @user3033933 Are all of the individual Test Plan workbook summary tabs named "Summary" (or are they all named identically) **and** are they all located in the same folder (same directory) on your computer **and** are all of the test plan file names something like "TestPlan1.xlsx", "TestPlan2.xlsx", etc.? If yes to all of these questions, then it is possible using this method. Let me know and I can modify the post accordingly if necessary.

Comment: @user3033933 Actually, I just thought of a solution even if the answer to the above questions are "no", but it will be much simpler if the answer is yes. I'll wait for you to respond before I modify my answer.

Comment: The Summary tab is named "Summary" for all the individual test plans. They are located in their own sub-folder (sub-folder named with the Test Plan Name) within a main folder called "Test Plans". Their names depends on the feature its testing e.g "Loans.xlsx","New Users and Accounts.xlsx" etc.

Comment: @user3033933 So for example would the test plan called "Loans.xlsx" be located in directory (for example): "C:\ (whatever)\Test Plans\Loans\Loans.xlsx"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158997/discussion-between-user3033933-and-imaginaryhuman072889).